# I need to hide the old link data once a different link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, hide, show

Image of what is working:

[image: image of what is working].

I have links set up to where when you click it, some text data will show underneath it.  Once a different link is clicked, I need the data from the previous clicked link to be hidden.  here is what I have so far.

```
$('#area7').click(function () {
    $('#output').empty();
    factory.getAttrData()
    .then((data) =>{
        data.forEach(element => {
            if (element.area_id === 7){
                $('#output').append(attrHBS(element));            }

        });
    });
});


 $(document).on("click", ".test", function(){
     $(this).next().slideToggle();
 });


//this is the appended code in handlebars
  <div>
    <h4 class ="test">
        <a href="#">{{name}}_({{type_id}})
        </a>
    </h4>
    <div id="show" class ="hidden">{{description}}
        <br>
        {{#if times}}{{times}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the relevant HTML and a working snippet

Comment: every dynamically created div has the class of .hidden in CSS with display :none. every H4 tag (link) has a class of .test. i would show a picture of what is happening so far but I do not think I am able to.

Comment: adam Azad, the html is dynamically created. The code i posted works, i just need extra help to make the text from one link go away when a different one is clicked.

Comment: @davidhazlettjr can you provide the code that dynamically creates the html?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, but it is in handlebars

Comment: David, I posted an answer with some jQuery to get you started. Even though you're in handlebars, you should be able to inspect the elements in the browser and provide some HTML like the others have asked. I'd suggest taking some of this code and try to implement it and then maybe ask a new, more specific question with all of the relevant code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an **Accordion** in many UI libraries. Here is a bare bones implementation. It uses delegated event handlers so dynamically adding to the DOM should not be an issue. You'll see that we can use the + operator in CSS and the .next() method from jQuery to target the collapsible sections. All you really need is to wrap these sections in a container that helps you identify them in the js.

```js
$( document ).on( 'click', ' .accordion h4', function() {

  let isOpen = $( this ).next( 'div').is(':visible');
  
  $( ' .accordion h4 + div' ).slideUp();

  if ( ! isOpen ) {
    $( this ).next().stop().slideDown();
  }
  
});
```

```css
.accordion h4 {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.accordion h4:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion h4 + div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
<h4 class="handle">Section 1</h4>
<div>
  <p>Content for section 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam semper ultrices sapien nec commodo. Pellentesque consectetur lacinia ornare. Morbi sit amet elementum mi. Nam sagittis turpis eget mi sollicitudin hendrerit. Mauris eget fermentum urna. Duis eu sapien finibus, pharetra tortor eu, faucibus lectus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus ligula, tincidunt at tristique ac, porttitor pellentesque tellus. Ut a cursus purus. In dolor tortor, finibus quis semper eu, tristique a urna. Quisque nisi dolor, scelerisque vel cursus sed, lacinia ac metus. Maecenas pretium hendrerit interdum. Nam mattis augue vel varius elementum. Sed mollis, libero sit amet tempus vestibulum, quam leo imperdiet odio, iaculis lobortis tellus odio vel orci. Suspendisse potenti. Ut ut nunc vulputate, tempus eros id, scelerisque est. Curabitur tincidunt nisl nisl, scelerisque ultrices urna condimentum sed</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="handle">Section 2</h4>
<div>
  <p>Content for section 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam semper ultrices sapien nec commodo. Pellentesque consectetur lacinia ornare. Morbi sit amet elementum mi. Nam sagittis turpis eget mi sollicitudin hendrerit. Mauris eget fermentum urna. Duis eu sapien finibus, pharetra tortor eu, faucibus lectus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus ligula, tincidunt at tristique ac, porttitor pellentesque tellus. Ut a cursus purus. In dolor tortor, finibus quis semper eu, tristique a urna. Quisque nisi dolor, scelerisque vel cursus sed, lacinia ac metus. Maecenas pretium hendrerit interdum. Nam mattis augue vel varius elementum. Sed mollis, libero sit amet tempus vestibulum, quam leo imperdiet odio, iaculis lobortis tellus odio vel orci. Suspendisse potenti. Ut ut nunc vulputate, tempus eros id, scelerisque est. Curabitur tincidunt nisl nisl, scelerisque ultrices urna condimentum sed</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="handle">Section 3</h4>
<div>
  <p>Content for section 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam semper ultrices sapien nec commodo. Pellentesque consectetur lacinia ornare. Morbi sit amet elementum mi. Nam sagittis turpis eget mi sollicitudin hendrerit. Mauris eget fermentum urna. Duis eu sapien finibus, pharetra tortor eu, faucibus lectus.</p>
  <p>Curabitur risus ligula, tincidunt at tristique ac, porttitor pellentesque tellus. Ut a cursus purus. In dolor tortor, finibus quis semper eu, tristique a urna. Quisque nisi dolor, scelerisque vel cursus sed, lacinia ac metus. Maecenas pretium hendrerit interdum. Nam mattis augue vel varius elementum. Sed mollis, libero sit amet tempus vestibulum, quam leo imperdiet odio, iaculis lobortis tellus odio vel orci. Suspendisse potenti. Ut ut nunc vulputate, tempus eros id, scelerisque est. Curabitur tincidunt nisl nisl, scelerisque ultrices urna condimentum sed</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  its not quite working for me so far, but i am sure i will get it up and running.  Thanks for the help.